# I need to create a VIEW from an existing TABLE and MAP an additional COLUMN to that VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL. What I am trying to do is create a view from an existing table. I also need to add a new column to the view which maps to the values of an existing column in the table.

So within the view, if the value in a field for Col_1 = A, then the value in the corresponding row for New_Col = C etc

Does this even make sense? Would I use the CASE clause? Is mapping in this way even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the Case clause is one way you could handle this, there are others but it depends on what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: A `VIEW` is just *"a virtual table whose contents are defined by a query."* It doesn't replicate the definition of the table(s), functions, other views (though nesting views is a bad idea) it references. It can have more columns, less columns, aggregate them, whatever, it's effectively just pre-written `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Fairly easy to do. Can you add some example data to the question?

Comment: @Lamu -- all select statements are written -- A view is pre compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a mapping or lookup table

For example consider the following LOOKUP table.

```
COL_A NEW_VALUE
----  -----
A     C
B     D
```

Then you can have a query like this:

```
 SELECT A.*, LOOK.NEW_VALUE
 FROM TABLEA AS A
 JOIN LOOKUP AS LOOK ON A.COL_A = LOOK.COL_A
```

This is what DimaSUN is doing in his query too -- but in his case he is creating the table dynamically in the body of the query.

Also note, I'm using a JOIN (which is an inner join) so only results in the lookup table will be returned.  This could filter the results.  A LEFT JOIN there would return all data from A but some of the new columns might be null.

Comment: Sure it's like my but more simple example, but You have to do `left join` not `join`

Comment: Thank you so much for all the input. For all I know my question could have already been answered. While I go through and try to better understand your answers, I thought I'd add some more information regarding the question just in case.

I have to create a view with select columns from an existing table (easy enough). I have to then add a brand new column to the view (not possible?) which contains values that map directly (are dependent upon) the values of one of the existing columns in the view.

I have considered CASE clause, TEMP tables and still am stuck.

Thanks so much

Comment: @HS -- I understand your question.  My query above could be a view ... just add `CREATE VIEW NAME AS` before the query.  This is how I would do it if I was creating a view.  It is faster than a CASE statement and If you want to change the mapping you can do so by changing the table and not having to change the view.  I've done this in production many times for many use cases.

Comment: Hi, this solution worked out great. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If You have restricted list of replaced values You may hardcode that list in query

```
select T.*,map.New_Col 
from ExistingTable T
left join ( 
  values 
   ('A','C')
  ,('B','D')
) map (Col_1,New_Col) on map.Col_1 = T.Col_1
```

In this sample You hardcode 'A' -> 'C' and 'B' -> 'D'

In general case You better may to use additional table ( see Hogan answer )

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @LemonKazi - is that explanation Ok ?

Comment: Yeah ok now. tx :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a view is an instance of a table/a replica provided that there is no alteration to the original table. So, as per your query you can manipulate the data and columns in a view by using case.

```
  Create View viewname as 
     Select *, 
           case when column=a.value then 'C' 
             .... 
             ELSE
           END 
     FROM ( Select * from table) a
```

Comment: Why do you have the sub-select that just selects `*`?  Why not just select directly from the table?  You also have an else with no value.  This is not valid SQL.